# Invoke-expression output on Screen and in a variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to store output from `Invoke-expression` into a variable as well as on screen. I have PS logging which automatically log everything as `Write-Host` in a file. Now I am using `Invoke-Expression` which seems to either print the output on Screen or to a variable, I need both

All that I have tried is:

```
$var = "C:\ER\work\Canny.exe -Init ER\ER2 Get-ip"

$val = Invoke-Expression $var
```

This doesn't print anything on Screen so I am unable to know if there are any issues while running. I later do a `Write-Host` of `$val` which logs it but its sometimes too late to know what happened
If I use:

```
Invoke-Expression $var
```

Nothing is logged (obviously), but there is console output and if I want to see after sometime for logs what happened, I have no way of Investigating.
I have also tried :

```
Invoke-Expression $var -OutVariable out
```

OR

```
Invoke-Expression $var -OutVariable $out
```

This is of no use here. I have also created a script block and tried with

```
Invoke-Command
```

but again of no use I just need it to print the output on Screen as well as to a variable.

Answer (score 13):

`Invoke-Expression -Command $var -OutVariable out` should work (variable + console output), but there's something weird going on. It works in ISE, but in a normal PowerShell console I get an empty `ArrayList`. If you pipe it to another command like `Out-String` it works (but this would return a single multi-line string).

```
Invoke-Expression -Command $var | Out-String -OutVariable out
```

Either I'm forgetting something or it might be a bug with `Invoke-Expression`.

A workaround would be to use [`Tee-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) which behaves the same as `-OutVariable`.

> The Tee-Object cmdlet redirects output, that is, it sends the output
>   of a command in two directions (like the letter "T"). It stores the
>   output in a file or variable and also sends it down the pipeline. If
>   Tee-Object is the last command in the pipeline, the command output is
>   displayed at the prompt.

Example:

```
Invoke-Expression $var -OutVariable | Tee-Object -Variable out
```

or (to a file):

```
Invoke-Expression $var -OutVariable | Tee-Object -FilePath c:\text.txt
```

Be aware that it overwrites the content in `$out`.

Answer (score 2):

This is where the cmdlet `Tee-Object` comes in handy. You can pipe your `Invoke-Command` to it, and specify if you want to store the output as a variable or a file, and it will both store the data as you specify, as well as pass it down the pipe (to be output to screen, if that is what you want).

```
Invoke-Expression $var | Tee-Object C:\Path\To\File.txt
```

Comment: This starts my Exe to fail:

Comment: invoke-expression $expr ; works well,   Invoke-Expression $var | Tee-Object -Variable xyz  ; exe gives  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I see that you found a solution, but I'm guessing that `(Invoke-Expression $var) | Tee-Object -Var xyz` would probably work, but that's going to make the executable finish its output before it tries to pass the info down the pipe.