# Invoke-Expression - write output to console but dont return it from function

Tags: powershell, io, stdout, powershell-5.1

I want to call `Invoke-Expression` inside a function and print the output of the command to the console but don't return it from the function since I want to return a specific value from it.

```
function Foo {
    $command = 'mvn clean package "-Dmaven.test.skip"'
    Invoke-Expression -Command $command | Write-Host

    $result = 'computed return value'
    return $result
}


$fooResult = Foo
Write-Output "fooResult is: ${fooResult}"
```

This works, but I want to avoid using the evil `Write-Host` function, so I tried `Write-Information` instead.
But I it seems you can't pipe the output of the `Invoke-Expression` to `Write-Information`. When I simply replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Information` it behaves like the `-MessageData` Parameter is not provided (similar when explicitly stating `-MessageData`).

Is there a way to write the output of `Invoke-Expression` to the console, but avoid returning it from the function without using `Write-Host`?

Comment: "but I want to avoid using the evil `Write-Host` function" - the exact behavior you want (bypass streams, write directly to host) is the very reason `Write-Host` is sometimes described as evil - in other words, you _want to be evil_ here :)

Comment: I think there are more disadvantages of using `Write-Host`. As I understand it, I can't redirect the output of it to a file e.g. when I want to redirect all the output of the whole script to a file when invoking it, no?

Answer (score 1):

You try with `OutVariable`

```
function Foo {
    $command = 'mvn clean package "-Dmaven.test.skip"'
    Invoke-Expression -Command $command -OutVariable OutputData | Out-Null

    Write-Information -MessageData "INFO: $OutputData" -INFA "Continue"
    return "something else"
}
```

Comment: Doing this Powershell tells me that `$OutputData` is `NULL`

Comment: I'm sorry, updated my post, please try again.

Comment: Now `$OutputData` contains the output but the whole output is still returned from the function as well. Please test your code before posting it.
Also the linebreaks seem to not be there anymore.

Comment: I edited my post again, and tested code, I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by "missing line breaks" I don't have `mvn` installed.

Comment: This should work, `$outputData` is being directed to the `Information Stream` while `something else` is directed to std out

Comment: Now only `Write-Output "fooResult is: ${fooResult}"` doesn't print the Linebreaks. Except that it works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Output to the screen is the Powershell default unless you tell it to do otherwise.
So, Write-* is almost moot, in many cases. Yet, folks have their reasons for using Write-* cmdlets.

There are several ways to write to the screen and even save to a variable and write to the screen at the same time.

- variable squeezing
- Out-String
- Out-Host
- Tee-Object

The aforementioned and more have been regularly covered.

Example web hits:

https://ridicurious.com/2017/06/30/3-ways-to-store-display-results-infrom-a-powershell-variable-at-the-same-time

https://mikefrobbins.com/2014/03/28/powershell-output-the-result-of-a-command-and-assign-it-to-a-variable-in-one-line

```
Get-Process a* -OutVariable process
($process = Get-Process a*)
Get-Process a* | Tee-Object -Variable p
```

Your post can even be seen as a duplicate of this similar use case:

[Invoke-expression output on Screen and in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330115/invoke-expression-output-on-screen-and-in-a-variable)

```
Invoke-Expression $var -OutVariable | Tee-Object -Variable out 

Invoke-Expression $var | Tee-Object C:\Path\To\File.txt
```

Running executables from Powershell is also a well-documented use case. See this from MS.

• PowerShell: Running Executables

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Comment: The `Tee-Object` writes the output to the pipeline, which leads to the function including it in the return value, which I want to avoid.